# ReactiveUI Fody [Reactive] attribute not working in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, reactiveui, fody

I've tried following the documentation for ReactiveUI.Fody.

https://github.com/kswoll/ReactiveUI.Fody

1. Added the FodyWeavers.xml the generated file to the shared project.

```
<Weavers xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="FodyWeavers.xsd">
  <ReactiveUI />
</Weavers>
```

2. Added the [Reactive] attribute to the property in the shared project.

```
    [Reactive]
    public int MyNumber
    {
       get;
       set;
    }
```

3. Added references to the ReactiveUI.Fody 16.3.10 Nuget package to my Android, iOS & Shared project.

The property never updates to a newly set value.

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: please post the relevant code

Comment: And add link to the installation instructions you are following. Not sure if its still needed, but does FodyWeavers.xml contain line `<ReactiveUI />`?

Comment: Probably deeper than you want/need to go, but might be worth looking at https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/tree/main/integrationtests/IntegrationTests.XamarinForms and https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/tree/main/integrationtests/IntegrationTests.XamarinForms.Android. Not sure exactly how to run those, but they presumably have been verified against current Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: Added extra information

Answer (score 0):

For ReactiveUI.Fody 16.3.10, you need to ensure that The minimum version of Xamarin Android is Android 11.0, with SDK 30 and .Net Standard minimum version is 2.0.

Make sure your AndroidManifest.xml has SDK 30 as the target SDK.

If you want to dynamically refresh data in Xamarin Forms, using the INotifyPropertyChanged interface is also a good choice. For information about its use, you can refer to [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/binding-mode#viewmodels-and-property-change-notifications).

Comment: The target SDK is 30 and .NET Standard version is 2.0 but, still getting the same issue

Comment: The link I provided is also a very common method, you can try it.

Comment: The requirement is to get Fody working. I already know about the INotifyPropertyChanged interface